# How to clear ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an event from where i call an Ajax function. From that ajax function i want to return a string, But the problem is that function also called some other functions and return some value.

The problem is the ajax called page return the whole sting that is returned from each and every functions, i mean Inherited.

**Ajax Event:**

```
$(".close_some").on("click", function(){
    $.get("close_some.php", { id : data_id, close_date_time : close_date_time }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response === "success"){
            document.location.reload(true);
        }else{
            alert('Some problem');
        }
    });
});
```

**close_some.php**

```
$col = someFunction($id); //this function also called another function where a return statement works
include_once "some_page.php";
echo 'success';
```

**someFunction()**

```
function someFunction($id){
    $sql = "SELECT `demo` FROM `some_problems` WHERE id = '$id'";   
    ...
    return departmentName($dept_id);
}
```

Now when i see at the `response` its a long string, but i need only the `success` how can i remove other responses??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Having a really hard time understanding what your real problem is and what exactly you are trying to do or what your code needs to do differently. If the string you see in response isn't `"success"` show what it contains

Comment: I need only `success` to my response, not other returned value.

Comment: Well we have no idea what is in `"some_page.php";`. All that we can see is one simple echo of "success". if there is any estra whitepsce which isn't uncommon for a php strin use `trim()` in success

Comment: in the `someFunction` function i have some returned value that is concatenate to the response..

Comment: OK.. and how are we to help with that when we can't see any of that code?

Comment: @charlietfl Sir, I update my question with the `someFunction()` definition.

Comment: A `return` in `someFunction()` doesn't echo anything. What is in `some_page.php`? You are not making this easy. Can you not restructure your php to only send one response? I agree with above about sending json is the best but a string will also work

Comment: @charlietfl, I got the result, Thanks for your support. Just need a `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: For future reference to help avoid confusion suggest reading [ask]

Comment: sorry for confusion, I have a lots of code with in it, If i optimize than some people demanding  code so i add them, I think i had a simple problem. But thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bufferize output of `some_page.php` using [output control functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) like this:

```
ob_start();
$col = someFunction($id);
include_once "some_page.php";
ob_end_clean();
echo 'success';
```

Comment: This is amazing ! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

> It seems you are echoing or returning streams from some functions you are calling from this one. You shouldn't echo values / strings directly from functions.

The solution for your problem is `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean()` functions.

so your code will look like.

```
<?php

ob_start();

$col = someFunction(....); //this function also called another function where a return statement works
include_once "some_page.php";

ob_end_clean();
echo 'success';
```

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible that ajax store returned value as `Buffer`, You better check your functions is there any `echo` or not, I am sure you have some echo in the `someFunction`.

We use the `ob_start()` to store the output as buffer, i don't think you do it in your code.

If your function has no echo then simply use `ob_end_clean()` before the `echo "success";`.

I think there are some answers which is informative to you, all the best.

Comment: Yes i have an echo in my sub function, Thanks for the support.